# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing when opening Robo 3T

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

[image: screenshot 1]

After installing the Robo 3T this is not opening showing `api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` is a missing error. I have downloaded some `.dll` file but I don't know how to use that file in our system.

Comment: That dll file is part of the Visual C++ redistributable.  Try getting a fresh copy from the Microsoft download site.